# can not find storekit.framework

Tags: iphone

after I install xcode 3.1.2,when I add existing frameworks, I can not find storekit.framework.

however in xcode 3.0.1, I did not find the problem.

what is wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the problem but the store kit is

```
StoreKit.framework
```

If this is not the problem, have a look at the Frameworks directory that xcode is using ...

- Create a simple project
- Right click on one of the frameworks under 'groups & files' e.g. UIKit.framework
- Select 'Reveal in finder'
- Ensure that the StoreKit.framework is present

If it is not there and you are able to find the framework elsewhere on your disk, you can add this directory to the 'Framework Search Paths' on the 'Build' tab of the project settings.

Hope that helps

"It works on my machine!!!"

Liam